# Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (160, 1000)

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm getting this error when I try and use an RNN model with my dataset. This is a stripped-down version of my model and dataset but it produces exactly the same error - [dropbox.com/sh/1a2guzsk4afp94r/AACkOQ1UibLZAhzGoyZJtVcqa?dl=0](https://dropbox.com/sh/1a2guzsk4afp94r/AACkOQ1UibLZAhzGoyZJtVcqa?dl=0)

The training data consists of lists of floats each 1000 floats long. For example,

```
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.55 0.2  0.5  0.85 0.8  0.2
 0.2  1.   0.2  0.2  0.5  0.75 0.3  0.5  0.5  0.3  0.85 0.65 0.15 0.4
 0.3  0.6  0.05 0.15 0.85 0.5  0.45 0.45 0.05 0.25 0.5  0.45 0.05 0.1
 0.45 0.9  0.35 0.35 0.65 0.15 0.45 0.3  0.3  0.6  0.2  0.2  0.05 0.55
 0.45 0.75 0.5  0.5  1.   0.5  1.   0.6  0.45 0.05 0.45 0.4  0.05 0.05
 0.8  0.05 0.85 0.85 0.8  0.7  0.9  0.65 0.2  1.   0.3  0.85 0.8  0.7
 0.95 0.2  0.7  0.95 0.95 0.2  0.2  0.25 0.6  0.7  0.3  0.25 0.15 0.2
 0.7  0.15 0.5  0.35 0.1  0.15 0.2  0.2  0.5  0.2  0.65 0.8  0.15 0.6
 0.2  0.2  0.2  0.6  0.65 0.05 0.3  0.8  0.7  0.05 0.65 0.3  0.8  0.7
 0.05 0.85 0.65 0.65 0.45 0.45 0.65 0.75 0.85 0.8  0.65 0.15 0.25 0.65
 0.2  0.9  0.5  0.45 0.2  1.   0.9  0.8  0.6  0.05 0.5  0.25 0.85 0.6
 0.75 0.85 1.   0.6  0.1  0.25 0.4  0.4  0.25 0.85 0.85 0.05 0.2  0.45
 0.3  0.45 0.2  0.5  1.   0.65 0.1  0.4  0.7  0.05 0.05 1.   0.45 0.1
 0.85 0.25 0.4  0.05 0.5  1.   0.55 1.   0.6  0.3  0.15 0.8  0.9  0.5
 1.   0.4  0.4  0.85 0.9  0.3  0.45 0.35 0.75 0.9  0.6  0.05 0.55 0.2
 0.6  0.5  0.1  0.8  0.45 0.45 0.1  0.85 0.9  0.8  0.25 0.5  0.7  0.05
 0.45 0.3  0.9  0.5  0.45 0.65 0.7  0.2  0.05 1.   0.6  0.9  0.1  0.1
 0.85 0.25 0.2  0.5  0.4  0.8  0.7  0.6  0.4  0.7  0.3  0.3  0.5  0.65
 0.8  0.8  0.25 0.25 0.6  0.65 0.9  0.7  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.45 0.8  0.9
 0.6  0.95 0.45 0.5  0.4  0.8  0.2  0.25 0.05 0.1  0.8  0.4  0.45 0.1
 0.85 0.15 0.65 0.5  0.5  0.5  0.55 0.05 0.5  1.   0.5  0.2  0.25 0.85
 0.85 0.05 0.65 0.2  0.05 0.1  0.45 0.9  0.1  0.15 0.6  0.65 0.75 0.75
 0.5  0.2  0.35 0.75 0.75 0.35 0.35 0.85 0.45 0.15 0.35 0.85 0.5  0.6
 0.05 0.5  0.5  0.25 0.7  0.15 0.8  0.45 0.85 0.7  0.45 0.85 0.4  0.1
 0.6  0.7  0.05 0.1  0.15 0.85 0.9  0.5  0.05 0.45 0.75 0.75 0.5  0.15
 0.55 0.45 0.85 0.5  0.85 0.75 0.6  0.2  0.5  0.5  0.9  0.7  0.75 0.95
 0.7  0.3  0.5  0.25 0.7  0.2  0.55 0.2  0.15 0.5  0.25 0.3  0.05 0.75
 0.3  0.2  0.2  0.35 0.5  0.05 0.35 0.75 0.55 0.05 0.05 0.9  0.55 0.95
 0.5  0.6  0.05 0.5  0.35 0.65 0.6  0.55 0.65 0.15 0.9  0.4  0.25 0.6
 1.   0.4  0.45 0.55 0.9  0.9  0.2  0.6  0.45 0.65 0.45 0.7  0.75 1.
 0.5  0.5  0.5  0.45 0.3  0.65 0.9  0.6  0.1  0.3  0.45 0.85 0.85 0.9
 0.05 0.05 0.3  0.5  0.4  0.3  0.5  0.1  0.3  0.3  0.05 1.   0.5  0.6
 0.4  0.6  0.1  0.65 0.65 0.2  0.75 0.5  0.05 0.25 0.2  0.5  0.3  0.55
 0.05 0.4  0.15 0.7  0.25 0.85 0.9  0.9  0.25 0.2  0.15 0.9  0.45 0.3
 0.45 0.45 0.8  0.8  0.45 0.8  0.8  0.5  0.7  0.85 0.3  0.4  0.3  0.25
 0.2  0.6  0.5  0.15 0.6  0.5  0.75 0.15 0.35 0.5  0.15 0.3  0.05 0.9
 0.65 0.9  0.6  0.5  0.2  0.75 0.45 0.35 0.7  0.6  0.45 0.9  0.85 0.7
 0.4  0.25 0.65 0.65 0.3  0.4  0.9  0.85 0.1  0.6  0.2  1.   0.15 0.4
 0.65 0.5  0.85 0.9  0.45 0.4  0.75 0.55 1.   0.7  0.45 0.9  0.2  0.5
 0.5  0.35 0.6  1.   0.6  0.5  1.   0.45 0.8  0.5  0.45 0.6  0.85 0.2
 0.2  0.9  0.3  0.45 0.45 0.75 1.   0.5  0.7  0.8  0.3  0.4  0.85 0.95
 0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.4  1.   0.25 0.75 0.8  0.9  0.15 0.15 0.25 0.85
 0.2  0.45 0.5  0.7  0.2  0.1  0.9  0.9  0.45 0.95 0.45 0.2  0.75 0.4
 0.2  0.85 0.2  0.9  0.3  0.15 0.55 0.95 0.5  0.5  0.85 0.55 0.45 0.2
 0.6  0.4  0.2  0.7  0.3  0.45 0.6  0.4  0.5  0.2  0.45 0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
```

Data is padded with 0s so that all sequences are 1000 elements long.

Here is the code for the model I'm using (Use dropbox link if you want to download it)

```py
    import numpy as np
        from sklearn.utils import shuffle
        import tensorflow as tf
        from tensorflow import keras
        from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
        from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
        import numpy as np


        def main():
            posData = createListOfSequences('PositiveData.txt')
            negData = createListOfSequences('NegativeData.txt')

            # Shuffle both
            np.random.shuffle(posData)
            np.random.shuffle(negData)

            # Create target lists
            PosTargets = [1.0] * len(posData)
            NegTargets = [0.0] * len(negData)

            # Combine PosData and NegData into 1 list
            Sequences = posData + negData
            Targets = PosTargets + NegTargets

            # shuffle sequences but maintain link to targets
            (Sequences, Targets) = shuffle(Sequences, Targets)

            # make all sequences 1000 in length
            for sequence in Sequences:
                sequence = padWithZero(1000, sequence)

            Sequences = np.array(Sequences)
            Targets = np.array(Targets)

            FitModel(Sequences, Targets)


        def FitModel(data, target):
            trainPercentage = 0.8
            splitValue = round(len(data) * trainPercentage)

            (x_train, y_train) = data[0:splitValue], target[0:splitValue]
            (x_test, y_test) = data[splitValue:len(
                data)], target[splitValue:len(target)]

            model = Sequential()

            model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu',
                           input_shape=(1000, 1), return_sequences=True))
            model.add(Dropout(0.2))
            model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dropout(0.2))
            model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dropout(0.2))
            model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

            opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)

            model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                          loss='binary_crossentropy',
                          metrics=['accuracy'])

            model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))


        def padWithZero(targetLength, sequence):
            i = 0
            while not(len(sequence) >= targetLength):
                if (i % 2 == 0):
                    sequence.append(0.0)
                else:
                    sequence.insert(0, 0.0)
                i += 1
            return sequence


        def createListOfSequences(dataPath):
            DataAsString = []
            for line in open(dataPath):
                x = line.rstrip()
                DataAsString.append((x.split(',')))

            ListOfSequences = []

            for seq in DataAsString:
                listOfFloats = []
                for val in seq:
                    if '.' in val:
                        listOfFloats.append(float(val))
                ListOfSequences.append(listOfFloats)

            return(ListOfSequences)


        main()
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One formal note - please provide ```minimal``` reproducible example. Ask more targeted questions, don't provide such a long code and data. If needed you can break it into more questions.

Comment: Apologies, I thought my dropbox link was a minimal reproducible example. I'll try and minimize it more next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, LSTM needs input in 3 dimensions. You can reshape like this:

```py
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1])
```

Basically, turning shape `(a, b)` into `(a, 1, b)`.

Comment: I'm now getting this error: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have shape (1000, 1) but got array with shape (1, 1000)`

Comment: Tried switching it round to get `(1000,1)` but that just produces another error

Comment: Does your `input_shape` argument correspond to `x_train.shape[1:]`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question sorry. What do you mean does it correspond to it?

Comment: In this line: `model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(1000, 1), return_sequences=True))`, the `input_shape` argument should be `(x_train.shape[1:])`.